# Beamer and latex -> dvi -> ps ->pdf problem

Tags: beamer, pdf, compiling

I am trying to create a beamer presentation and I have a compilation problem. When I use pdflatex, everything is OK. However, I need latex + dvi to ps + ps to pdf. This is since I draw some pictures in inkscape and then export them to ps. However, when I try to compile my code with latex + dvi to ps + ps to pdf, **the titles of the blocks are covered with a black rectangle and hence invisible.** I would be grateful if someone could point out what is the issue. I have tried to do it with both Texmaker and Texstudio and the result is the same.

Here is the code and the screenshot of the resulting pdf.

```
\documentclass[10 pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\mode<presentation>
{
    \usetheme{boadilla}
    \usetheme{default}      
    \usecolortheme{default}  
    \usefonttheme{default} 
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
    \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 


    \title[description]{A wonderful title}
\author{me} 
\institute{myinstitute}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[plain]
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{frame} \frametitle{Good morning!}
        
        \begin{block}{My title is covered by a black rectangle}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Objects: 
            \end{itemize} 
        \end{block}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: This is the resulting pdf]

Comment: Use a recent Ghostscript (v. 9.52 or newer) and add option `-dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY` to the `ps2pdf` command.

Comment: @AlexG thank you for your interest. Can you please expand a bit? Because I've just installed  the newest version of Ghostscript and put "ps2pdf.exe -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY %.ps" in the ps2pdf command and the problem persists.

Comment: "This is since I draw some pictures in inkscape and then export them to ps" Why the hell in ps? Expot to PDF and use pdflatex (or xlatex, ord  lualatex). End of the story.

Comment: @IvanBartulovic Check the Document Properties in your PDF viewer, esp. the Producer entry, for the Ghostscript version actually used. Some TeX distros, MiKTeX for instance, come with their own, outdated Ghostscript.

Comment: @Fran PostScript is cool ;)

Comment: if you are using miktex you need to set an environment variable to use an external ghostscript https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/218.  And don't use utf8x, with a new latex you can delete the inputenc line completly. utf8 is the default since two years at least.

Comment: You can use (E)PS images with pdflatex as well (since many years now), they will be converted automatically to pdf during inclusion, without the need for the shell-escape flag.

Comment: Thank you all. I suspect that  @Urlike Fisher and AlexG were right. I use MikTeX and there is some issue with ghostscript. Until I try to manage the situation, I will use pdflatex as a temporary solution. I use this compilation, since I need psfrag package, which allows me to label objects in the pictures with text and equations in \LaTeX mathmode.